# Improving code in C

Tags: c

i'm new to programming and i'm trying to return a couple errors if an inout is invalid. I've gotten the below code so far and it works but is there anything else I can do to improve on it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define pi 3.141593

int main(void)
{
    float inner_d, outer_d, surface_area, radius;

    printf("Enter the outer diameter:\n");
    scanf("%f", &outer_d);

    printf("Enter the inner diameter:\n");
    scanf("%f", &inner_d);

    if (inner_d >= outer_d)
    {
        printf("Inner diameter must be less than outer diameter\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (inner_d < 0 || outer_d < 0)
    {
        printf("Both outer and inner measurements must be possitive\n");
        return 0;
    }

    float inner_a = (inner_d / 2) * (inner_d / 2) * pi;
    float outer_a = (outer_d / 2) * (outer_d / 2) * pi;

    surface_area = outer_a - inner_a;

    printf("Your surface area is: %f\n", surface_area);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using if statements ? (https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson2.html) You can check for variables value that way and return errors if they aren't valid by using "return 1" (and you might want to printf a message first)

Comment: What do you mean “return” errors?  Do you mean “print an error message instead of the output”?

Comment: what about `if (inner_d < 0 || outer_d < 0 || inner_d >= outer_d) { return EXIT_FAILURE;}` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking for better options are too broad and opinion-based. You may be able to get help on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @xskxzr I disagree in this case. It wouldn't be a good question for CR, and although it is a bit vague here, the code shown clearly has **errors** wrt input validation and error checking, so I'd consider it on topic here.

Comment: Sorry guys what I wanted my program to actually do is if you input an invalid entry (eg. negative numbers or have the inner diameter higher than the outer) to print out either "Inner diameter must be greater than outer" or "both numbers must be positive" I have managed to accomplish this already though with the tips I've received here. Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to react on invalid input, the **very first thing** to do would be to check the actual **return value** of any function that reads or parses input -- here your `scanf()`. For the purpose of displaying an error message, it's quite simple:

```
if (scanf("%f", &outer_d) != 1) // expect exactly 1 successful conversion here
{
    fputs("Input error: not a number\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Note that you'll run into some problems with `scanf()` if your requirement is to retry after a wrong input. In this case, I recommend reading my [beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

---

Further hints:

- The return value from `main()` indicates success of failure of the whole program. There are two macros defined in `stdlib.h`: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` -> use them. Typically, `0` corresponds to `EXIT_SUCCESS`, so you shouldn't do `return 0;` after an error.
- Error messages (and, in general, "status/logging/debug" messages) go to `stderr`, not to `stdout`. This allows other processes or a user to distinguish between them, e.g. one could log all errors using `./your_program 2>error.log` and still see the normal output on screen. So use `fputs(..., stderr);` and/or `fprintf(stderr, "... %d ...", ...);` for your error messages.
- the `printf()` family of functions is for **formatting** output. If you don't have any formatting to do, use the `puts()` family of functions instead, see [man puts](https://linux.die.net/man/3/puts). It's not directly wrong to use `printf()` anyways, but it's wasteful and it **can** be dangerous because whatever you pass is treated as a format string, google "format string attack" for in-depth info.

  This is btw the conceptually same duality as with `scanf()` (for parsing input) and `fgets()` (for just reading it).

Comment: Thanks for the tips Felix!

Answer (score 3):

In C, the `main` function should return 0 upon a successful exit and some error code otherwise. This way you can distinguish between success and different errors. One way to do it is mentioned in the comment by @Stargateur:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define pi 3.141593

int main(void)
{
    float inner_d, outer_d, surface_area, radius;

    printf("Enter the outer diameter:\n");
    scanf("%f", &outer_d);

    printf("Enter the inner diameter:\n");
    scanf("%f", &inner_d);
    if (inner_d < 0 || outer_d < 0 || inner_d >= outer_d) { return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    float inner_a = (inner_d / 2) * (inner_d / 2) * pi;
    float outer_a = (outer_d / 2) * (outer_d / 2) * pi;  

    surface_area = outer_a - inner_a;

    printf("Your surface area is: %f\n", surface_area);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Niklas, thanks for steering me into the right direction.

Comment: Also, read about [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It can fail, and you should test that case.

Answer (score 0):

As I am getting you, you can use if else statement to check your validation and print error accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define pi 3.141593

int main(void)
{
   float inner_d, outer_d, surface_area, radius;

   printf("Enter the outer diameter:\n");
   scanf("%f", &outer_d);

   printf("Enter the inner diameter:\n");
   scanf("%f", &inner_d);

   if (inner_d <= 0.0) {
      printf("Inner_d must be positive number");
   }
   if (outer_d <= 0.0) {
      printf("Outer_d must be positive number");
   }
   if (inner_d > outer_d) {
      printf("Inner_d must less than outer_d");
   }

   float inner_a = (inner_d / 2) * (inner_d / 2) * pi;
   float outer_a = (outer_d / 2) * (outer_d / 2) * pi;

   surface_area = outer_a - inner_a;


   printf("Your surface area is: %f\n", surface_area);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, that does look tidier.